# how to get around a '-' in array path

Tags: javascript, jquery

I make a call to an API

The API returns a result like:

```
{saved-jobs:[{/*item*/},{/*item*/}]}
```

I want to access each 'saved-jobs' like so:

```
success: function(result){
        $.each(result.saved-jobs, function(i, saved_job){
            console.log(saved_job.job_id)
        });
    },
```

only thing is, the ' - ' in saved-jobs causes an error. I don't have the ability to modify the API and what it returns. how can I get around it?

Comment: Try `result['saved-jobs']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

`result["saved-jobs"]`

Comment: ah thanks, everyone gave the same answer but you were first by about 5 seconds :P will accept after 10 minutes is up

Answer (score 3):

You can access object properties using brackets too:

`result['saved-jobs']`

You can find more here: [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Answer (score 2):

Change `result.saved-jobs` to `result["saved-jobs"]`.